# How to read in input from chgport using subprocess correctly?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I have two different types of Arduino Mega 2560 boards. One can be detected easily using the command mode and the other chgport. I have no problem setting up subprocess to run the command mode. When I am setting up `subprocess.run` to run the command `chgport`, I do not get the same answer I got by manually typing the `chgport` into the command prompt.

I type `chgport` into Windows command line and I got:

```
COM5 = \Device\Serial2
```

I set up Python 3.7.2 command:

```
subprocess.run(["chgport"],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I got this output, which is not what I expected:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['chgport'], returncode=1, stdout=b'')
```

I expected:

```
stdout=b'COM5 = \Device\Serial2'
```

Code that I had tried:

```
a=subprocess.run(["chgport"],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print(a.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

***Hi I gave up on using subprocess so I use os.  The code below works.  First I redirect the output from mode into a file and then read the file.***

```
import os
import sys

dir=os.popen("echo %cd%").readlines()[0].strip("\n")+"\\"


os.popen("cd "+dir+ """&& mode>"""+dir+"junk")

com = os.popen("more "+dir+"junk | findstr COM""").readlines()
os.popen("del "+dir+"junk")
port=com[0]
first=port.find("COM")
second=port.find(":")

print(port[first:second])
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer.